# EPPLUS: how to check if all cell are valid?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using Excel's data validation lists, checking if the cell value is into a dynamic range (the cell values of another column).

The problem is that if I add a value into the source range (eg. "A"), I can input that value on the cell with data validation. But then, if I change the source (eg from "A" to "B") the cell with data validation is still "A".

In Excel there's a button that sets a red circle around invalid data, but client does not always check if everything is good.

Can I perform that check with EPPLUS?

Comment: Relevant thread: [Which .NET project can programmatically validate a cell's value out of the box based on Excel data validation constraints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518266/which-net-project-can-programmatically-validate-a-cells-value-out-of-the-box-b) (As of 11/22/2023, the answer is: none.)

Comment: The same question, but for NPOI: [How to programmatically evaluate Excel data validations using NPOI in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74204029/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-evaluate-excel-data-validations-using-npoi-in)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't suggest that this check can be performed.

- The EPPlus [Features](https://www.epplussoftware.com/Developers/Features) page mentions "*Create, read, modify, delete Data validations*" and links to the [Data Validation](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Data-validation) wiki page, but that is only about defining data validation rules programmatically - and not whether a cell's value conforms to a data validation rule.
- I've searched the source code and looked at [ExcelDataValidation.cs](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/blob/85c1fb77eca14f2b0c0c530cad67805ecd6db644/src/EPPlus/DataValidation/ExcelDataValidation.cs) and its various sub-types. Their "Validate" methods only check if the validation is properly defined according to Excel's rules.
- Found the [`InternalValidationEnabled`](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.2/api/OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.ExcelDataValidationCollection.html#OfficeOpenXml_DataValidation_ExcelDataValidationCollection_InternalValidationEnabled) property (see below), but I think it is only meant to check the consistency of the data validation rules themselves, and not if the cells conform to them.

To achieve what you're asking for, you'll have to use EPPlus to get the validation from the cell, interpret it depending on its type and evaluate the cell content. There is [an example](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus.Sample.NetCore/blob/508b83d6cb9496cea79bb94bd3d0fc15b98c250a/12-DataValidation/DataValidationSample.cs) that touches some of the cases and could give you an idea where this is heading.

Truth is, once data validation rules start to involve Excel formulas / functions, things will get complex. Built-in Excel functions are implemented in the Excel applications (web, desktop, mobile, etc.), so they will have to be implemented in the framework itself as well (in this case EPPlus). See Apache POI's [Excel function implementations](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/) in Java, for example. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518656/1498178) for more details.