# How to programmatically evaluate Excel data validations using NPOI?

Tags: excel, validation, .net-core, xlsx, npoi

I would like to programmatically check if cell value is valid using data validations already added to .xlsx template. There is a way to do that in Java using Apache POI [`DataValidationEvaluator`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.html) class, but I [can't find similar feature in any of the open-source libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77518266) for .NET.

I've tried iterating through validations from the sheet and validating the cell value, but I'm not sure if I need to implement low-level logic by myself or is there an already made API for validation evaluation?

```
foreach (var s in sheets)
{
  ISheet sheet = wb.GetSheet(s.Name);
  var validations = sheet.GetDataValidations();
  foreach (var v in validations)
  {
      var xssfValidation = (XSSFDataValidation)v;
      var xssfValidationConstraint = xssfValidation.ValidationConstraint;
      switch (xssfValidationConstraint.Operator)
          {
          case 0: 
                  // BETWEEN 
                  break;
          case 1: 
                  // EQUAL 
                  break;
          // ...
      }
}
```

Comment: NPOI is rather limited. EPPlus and ClosedXML are more popular and have more features. Check EPPlus' [data validations](https://github.com/EPPlusSoftware/EPPlus/wiki/Data-validation) page. ClosedXML [also supports data validations](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Data-Validation)

Comment: Worst case, you can use the low-level [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) to read data validation elements

Comment: I don't think EPPlus can do more according to this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68572460/epplus-how-to-check-if-all-cell-are-valid
I will look into ClosedXML, thx anyways

Answer (score 0):

#### 0. State of the art (as 11/22/2023)

The [`NPOI.SS.Formula.DataValidationEvaluator`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/master/main/SS/Formula/DataValidationEvaluator.cs) class seems to mirror Apache POI's [`DataValidationEvaluator`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.html) class, but NPOI's version only implemented the `IsType` method thus far. (For reference, here's Apache POI's [`isType`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.html#isType-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType-).)

There also seems to be [no .NET Excel project that natively supports this yet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77518267/1498178).

#### 1. Challenges

##### 1.1 Many validation types

There are at least [7 data validation types](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) in Excel<sup>**1**</sup>, each with its own requirements.

<sup>[1]: From the Open XML SDK for Microsoft Office: [`DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.DataValidation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.datavalidation?view=openxml-2.8.1) class' [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.datavalidation.type?view=openxml-2.8.1) property [values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.datavalidationvalues?view=openxml-2.8.1). NPOI provides the [`int GetValidationType`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/f1ecc1ebf13ce37599ca9e29720e60f7ea60f2d3/main/SS/UserModel/DataValidationConstraint.cs#L22-L28) method(?) and the [`ValidationType`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/f1ecc1ebf13ce37599ca9e29720e60f7ea60f2d3/main/SS/UserModel/DataValidationConstraint.cs#L61-L79) "enum" to check `int` against a specific type.</sup>

Personally, I mostly have to deal with the `List` type (which is usually used to implement drop-downs), where the possible values can be defined by

- listing the values explicitly (e.g., `'yes', 'no'`)

  ```
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFDataValidationConstraint
    {ExplicitListValues = [|"Yes"; "No"|];
     Formula1 = ""Yes, No"";
     Formula2 = null;
     Operator = 0;}
  ```
- a cell range reference (e.g., `=$E$2:$H$2`)

  ```
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFDataValidationConstraint 
    {ExplicitListValues = null;
     Formula1 = "$Q$2:$T$2";
     Formula2 = null;
     Operator = 0;}
  ```
- a [named range](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)

  ```
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFDataValidationConstraint 
    {ExplicitListValues = null;
     Formula1 = "Status";
     Formula2 = null;
     Operator = 0;}
  ```
- an Excel function / formula

  ```
  NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFDataValidationConstraint 
    {ExplicitListValues = null;
     Formula1 = "INDIRECT(V7)";
     Formula2 = null;
     Operator = 0;}
  ```

<sup>The sample outputs are from `dotnet fsi` (the F# REPL) using NPOI.</sup>

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77524422/drop-down-values-in-excel-cells-are-not-specified-in-data-validation-rules-and-g) where a drop-down list is created using a named range in column A, and column B's drop-downs are conditionally defined (using [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)) by a list data validation that also uses named ranges.

##### 1.2 Named ranges, built-in and custom functions / formulas

###### 1.2.1 The invocation of **formulas / functions** and **[named ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)** look the same.

Can you tell just by looking if the invocation `=status` is a named range or a function? There is no native `STATUS` function in Excel, so it may be either a custom VBA script or a named range. (At least, NPOI's `XSSFWorkbook` class has a [`GetAllNames`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/f1ecc1ebf13ce37599ca9e29720e60f7ea60f2d3/ooxml/XSSF/UserModel/XSSFWorkbook.cs#L1080C37-L1080C37) method, so named ranges can be eliminated fairly easily.)

###### 1.2.2 No way discriminate between custom scripts and built-in functions.

[Open XML SDK for Microsoft Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk?view=openxml-2.8.1) does not provide a way to list built-in functions. As far as I know, most popular .NET Excel projects build on Open XML - and they also have no such feature. (NPOI has no way to list VBA scripts, but one can dig them up using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk?view=openxml-2.8.1) by looking for [`VBAProjectPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.vbaprojectpart?view=openxml-2.8.1) instances.)

###### 1.2.3 How to evaluate Excel formulas / functions?

As mentioned above, built-in Excel functions are not part of the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk?view=openxml-2.8.1) and so one would have to re-implement them in the framework itself. At least, this is how Apache POI's [`DataValidationEvaluator`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.html) ([source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.java)) works: after jumping through a bunch of hoops<sup>**2**</sup>, eventually [`FormulaParser.parse`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaParser.html) ([source](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaParser.java)) will get called, and the validation evaluator will apply the [subset of Excel functions implemented in Java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/functions/) or throw an error.

<sup>[2]: [`DataValidationEvaluator`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/DataValidationEvaluator.java) [ `isValidCell` -> `isValid` -> `isValidValue` -> `getValidationValuesForConstraint`]
 -> [`WorkbookEvaluator`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/WorkbookEvaluator.java) [ `evaluateList` -> `evaluate` ]
 -> [`FormulaParser`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/poi/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaParser.java) [ `parse` ]</sup>

The same applies to custom VBA scripts as well. They can be set using [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk?view=openxml-2.8.1), but that's it.

NPOI has a way to re-calculate formulas, (F# again, sorry)

```ml
let recalculateFormulas (workbook: XSSFWorkbook) =
    let creationHelper = workbook.GetCreationHelper()
    let formulaEvaluator = creationHelper.CreateFormulaEvaluator()
    formulaEvaluator.EvaluateAll()
```

but this will only evaluate formula-type [cells](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/f1ecc1ebf13ce37599ca9e29720e60f7ea60f2d3/main/SS/UserModel/Cell.cs), and not the formulas embedded into data validations (see [`IDataValidationConstraint`](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/blob/f1ecc1ebf13ce37599ca9e29720e60f7ea60f2d3/main/SS/UserModel/DataValidationConstraint.cs)).