# Drop-down values in Excel cells are not specified in Data Validation rules and global search didn't find them in workbook, so where do they come from?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On top of values seemingly coming from nowhere in multiple columns, they also affect each other's behavior: In the GIF below, if the cells in the left column have no value selected, then there is no dropdown in the cells in the right column **and** they also don't accept arbitrary values (as a validation warning will pop up).

[image]

I know of the basic data validation drop-down methods:

1. Select a range of cells
2. Go to `Data` > `Data Validation`
3. Select "List" in `Allow`
4. At `Source`, either specify the values or select a range of cells that hold them

   [image]

For the columns in the GIF, `Source` shows stuff that's new to me:

- for the **left** column: `=Status`
- for the **right** column: `=INDIRECT(V7)` (the cell reference increments with every row)

There is no `=Status` Excel formula, I checked in the [official list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188). I did find the [`INDIRECT` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261), but the doc page doesn't make much sense in my case, even after looking at the examples.

I even listed all Data Validation rules programmatically using [NPOI](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi), but didn't find extra ones, and the ones defined on the two columns showed the same values as in the Excel app.

Answer (score 0):

It took a day and a half, but found it:

#### 1. LEFT column's valid values, `Assessed` and `Pending`

Started with the left column, because if it is not set, then the right column is "inactive", so it clearly has to trigger something. After several global workbook searches on the string `Pending`, I noticed that the cursor jumps to a place where there is nothing. It looked like a glitch, but once the search came full circle, the screen kept jumping to this empty place. Then I realized there are columns "missing": `AV`, `AW`, and `AX`.

[image]

After expansion:

[image]

#### 2. LEFT column still: The `=Status` formula in Data Validation rule

Again, [there is no built-in `Status` function in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-alphabetical-b3944572-255d-4efb-bb96-c6d90033e188), so where does it come from? Decided to enter `=Status` in an empty cell, and several things happened:

1. Once the "formula" was entered,

   - a tooltip came up showing `Status PART-IV-SERVICES!AV3:AV4` (in generic form: `Status <sheet_name>!<cell_range>` )
   - the cell range `AV3:AV4` got highlighted
2. After pressing enter, the blank cells were replaced with the content of the cells in the referenced range (i.e., `AV3:AV4`).

[image]

After selecting the highlighted range, the "cell selection textbox"(?) in the Formula Bar first showed the cell range, then it switched to `Status`. As it turns out, cells and cell ranges can be named (see article [Define and use names in formulas](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64)). So combining `=Status` and setting `List` in the Data Validation rule for the column achieves the drop-down effect.

#### 3. RIGHT column: INDIRECT function

The cells in the **right** column are empty, but their Data Validation rule is set to "List" and the "source" field is set to `=INDIRECT(<left_column_cell_ref>)`:

[image]

I still don't understand what the [`INDIRECT` documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) is trying to say, but this is what's happening: When a **left** column cell is populated with a value (in this case, with either `Assessed` or `Pending`), then the `INDIRECT(<cell_ref>)` becomes either `=Pending` or `=Assessed`.

The last piece of the puzzle is that I found two more [named ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64), `Pending` and `Assessed` (see image below), so when their names are called in a formula, they will behave the same as `=Status`, but with one level of indirection added to the mix. (Putting it this way, the name of the `INDIRECT` function does make sense, but I'm still confused how it is supposed to behave.)

[image]